# My question is to capitalise the first word of a string in hacker rank, and I am getting an error regarding the EOF error

Tags: python, eof

You are asked to ensure that the first and last names of people begin with a capital letter in their passports. For example, *alison heck* should be capitalised correctly as *Alison Heck*.

I had tried in online compilers like repl.it. I am getting a correct answer, but  I am getting when I am trying in hacker rank.

```
flag = True
while(flag):
    try:
        S = input()
        g = (S.title())
        print(g)
    except EOFError:
        flag = False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 26, in <module>
    s = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [strip()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_strip.htm) is what you need:

```
input().strip()
```

I think this should do it.

Comment: such short tips should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

They don't accept input in Hackerrack for some questions.
You just have to return the answer through their function.

```
# Complete the solve function below.
def solve(s):
    return (" ".join([x.lower().capitalize() for x in s.split(' ')]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def solve(s):
    return ' '.join(i.capitalize() for i in s.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.capwords()` method,

```
import string
def solve(s):    
     return string.capwords(s,' ')
```

This worked for me.